# Autoscaling AWS nodes in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I've found a few posts on a similar topic, but wanted to clarify:

If I am running Kubernetes in AWS (natively, e.g. by deploying with Kops), is there any mechanism that can deploy additional nodes to the AWS node ASG to cater for resource requirements?

For example, if I deploy a 2 worker node cluster (ASG) that has a total of 8gb of memory, and I create a few kubernetes deployments onto the cluster, where memory requirements become greater than 8gb, is there a mechanism that will abstractly scale the underlying ASG to provide the required resources with me needing to manually increase the size of the ASG?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [kubernetes autoscaler project](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler)?

It is AWS compatible so it should answer your requirements